# Sections of very ample line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, line-bundles

Let $f: C \to D$ a dominant morphism which is *not* an isomorphism between two irreducible, reduced, projective curves $C,D$ over an alg closed field $k$ (unsure if algebraically closedness is neccessary). Let $L$ be line bundle on $D$, $L^n = L^{\otimes n}$ it's $n$-th power and $K^m:= f^*L^m$ it's pullback. Assume that $K^m$ is *very ample*.

Question: Why $h^0(C, K^m) > h^0(D, L^m)$ is a proper inequality? That is why the case $h^0(C, K^m) = h^0(D, L^m)$ cannot happen if $k^m$ is very ample?

Recall Eoin's argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561326/morphism-to-projective-plane-mathbbp2) shows that $h^0(C, K^m) \ge h^0(D, L^m)$ since $f$ dominant implies that $O_D \to f_*O_C$ is injective and twisting by $L^m$ leads to injective map $L^m \to f_*O_C \otimes L^m= f_*(K^m)$ (the last one is projection formula). Well, why $h^0(C, K^m) > h^0(D, L^m)$.

my idea: $f$ is finite since between curves and since not isomorphism, we can find an affine open subscheme $U \subset D$ such that the restriction of $f$ to affine open $V:=f^{-1}(U) \subset C$ is not an isomorphism. We obtain a injective ring map $\varphi:R_U \to R_V$. The restriction wasn't an isomorphism thus it's not surjective. Twisting with local sections $L^m(U)$ of line bundle preserves the non surjectivity. Thus $\varphi \otimes id_{L^m(U)}: L^m(U) \to K^m(V)$ is still not surjective and we find a $s_V \in K^m(V)$ which haven't a preimage in $L^m(U)$.

Can we use very ampleness of $K^m$ to extend $s_V$ to a global section $s \in H^0(C,K^m)=K^m(C)$?

Comment: If $H^0(D, L^m)=H^0(C, K^m)$, then the map induced by $K^m$ factors through the $D$ and thus can not be an embedding by your assumption on $f$.

Comment: @Mohan: I think one point has to be clarfied: We assumed $K^m=f^*L^m$ is very ample and thus we obtain an closed embedding $i_C:C \to \mathbb{P}^n$ determined by $n+1$ sections $s_i \in H^0(C, K^m)$ (up to simultaneous multiplication by a factor from $k^*$) write suggestively : $i_C= [s_0: s_1:...: s_n]$. These $s_i$ are related to $i_C$ as these $s_i$ are nothing then pullbacks of the canonical map $i_C^*: kX_0 \oplus kX_1 \oplus ... \oplus kX_n=H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}(1)_{\mathbb{P}^n}) \to H^0(C, K^m) $ given by $X_i \mapsto i_C^*X_i =s_i$. Assume $H^0(D, L^m)=H^0(C, K^m)$.

Comment: We must to keep traking that this isomorphism comes from the pullback map $f^*:H^0(D, L^m)=H^0(C, K^m)$. That is $(f^*)^{-1}$ is well defined. Another map $i_D: D \to \mathbb{P}^n$ determined by $n+1$ sections $t_i:=(f^*)^{-1} s_i \in H^0(D, L^m)$.

That is we obtain a factorization of $k$-modules $i_C^*= f^* \circ i_D^*: \mathcal{O}(1)_{\mathbb{P}^n}) \to H^0(D, L^m) \to H^0(C, K^m) $. Why does it suffice to imply that $i_C$ also factorize, i.e. why $i_C^*= f^* \circ i_D^*$ imply $i_C= i_D \circ f: C \to D \to \mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: If we recall how the $s_i$ construct the map $i_C$: the $i_C$ is glued from locally defined affine maps $g_{s_i}: C_{s_i} \to D_+(X_i)$ defined on ring side by $\frac{X_j}{X_i} \mapsto \frac{s_j}{s_i}$. Do you want to say that the factorization $i_C^*= f^* \circ i_D^*$ implies that $f$ is also glued together from maps $f_{s_i}: D_{t_i} \to C_{s_i}, \frac{t_j}{t_i} \mapsto \frac{s_j}{s_i}$?

Comment: Problem: We not assumed that $L^m$ is ample. Thus we cannot expect that $D_{t_i}$ is affine. This a serious problem since we defined $$f_{s_i}$ on the *ring side* and we can only do it if we know that $D_{t_i}$ is affine because $Hom_{Sch}(X,Y) \cong Hom_{rings}(\Gamma(Y,O_Y), \Gamma(X,O_X))$ if and only if $Y$ is affine.

Comment: Could you clarify how the factorization of $i_C:C \to \mathbb{P}^n$ trough $D$ is concretly defined if we assume $H^0(D, L^m)=H^0(C, K^m)$? Hope I haven't explained the problem in a too confusing way.